# Selecting a Parent of an element when clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery

To summarize, I am trying to make it so that when a user clicks on a specific element on a page the pages reads the data value and matches it against a list of of possible values and redirects the user to a specific URL depending on the value.

The part I am stuck on is being able to get the value of a parent element when an element is clicked on.I need the value of the element with class="1" and because of the way the page is its only feasible that the user will click on the element with class="3".

I am using a simple alert test to see if I can access the value.

```js
document.onclick = function(event) {
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  $tar = target;

  alert($(tar).parents().eq(2).attr("data"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="1" data="123">
  <div class="2">
    <div class="3">

      This is my DIV
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a note, classes cannot start with a number, per W3C specification: In CSS, identifiers (including element names, **classes**, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen ( - ) and the underscore ( _ ); **they cannot start with a digit**, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. **EDIT**: As pointed out, this is merely for selectors - while it's perfectly valid in HTML, you'll have to do some dirty-work when referencing these classes using standard selectors in CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: @Santi: Classes *can* start with a digit, it's just that a class selector cannot start with an unescaped digit. (Same for IDs.) So for simplicity's sake, it's best not to use classes starting with a digit, but that's different from it not being allowed.

Comment: @ user: It's **well worth** your time to read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It only takes an hour, two tops, and it gives you the answers to questions like this, paying you back that hour or two almost immediately.

Comment: You have a typo: `$tar = target` ... `$(tar).parents()...` should be `$($tar).parents()...`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are correct. I realize now that the problem with starting a class/id etc with a number is not in the HTML itself, but rather the selector, as you mentioned. Thanks! I'll edit my comment to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to achieve this.

It's a *lot* easier if you don't start your class with a digit, because class selectors can't start with unescaped digits. So if we change 1, 2, and 3 to a, b, and c (and if we fix the typo [André pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41597978/selecting-a-parent-of-an-element-when-clicked-on/41598078#comment70398867_41597978)) you'd have:

```js
document.onclick = function(event) {
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  $tar = target;

  alert($($tar).closest(".a").attr("data"));
}
```

```html
<div class="a" data="123">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">

      This is my DIV
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(Also note that you can use jQuery to hook up that event handler, rather than using `onclick =`.)

But if you absolutely had to use 1, 2, and 3 (which I **do not** recommend):

```js
document.onclick = function(event) {
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  $tar = target;

  alert($($tar).closest(".\\31").attr("data"));
}
```

```html
<div class="1" data="123">
  <div class="2">
    <div class="3">

      This is my DIV
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know you're only going up two steps, then the following should be fine:

```js
document.onclick = function(event) {
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  $tar = target;

  alert($($tar).parent().parent().attr("data"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a" data="123">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">

      This is my DIV
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```